# Delay when reading from TCPClient

Tags: .net, tcpclient

I have the following code, which reads data of unknown size into a memory stream.

```
Dim cl As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
cl.Connect(host, port)
Dim st As IO.Stream = cl.GetStream()
Dim bytes(50000) As Byte
Dim mem As New IO.MemoryStream()
Dim len As Integer = 0
Do
  len = st.Read(bytes, 0, 50000)
  mem.Write(bytes, 0, len)
Loop While len > 0
mem.Close()
```

It works fine, but the only problem is that the last read always blocks for 20 seconds before returning 0.
I'm assuming this is some sort of timeout. Is there any way to shorten or eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that behavior on my system, Read returns 0 instantly when there is no more data available. Are you sure you don't set any other properties on the TcpClient, like `cl.NoDelay = false`?

You could try checking that `cl.Available > 0` before calling st.Read, but that should not really be neccesary.

You should also handle the case of -1 returned from Read (when the TCP stream have been closed). Otherwise mem.Write will throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception at you.

Comment: The delay is probably due to the way the server sends the data. Checking cl.Available is not good because the server may not be finished sending the data (I did try it and got incomplete data). So I do need a delay, I'm just looking for a way to make it shorter. I'm guessing the 20 seconds are defined somewhere. I actually do handle EOS, but left it out for simplicity.

Comment: Strange. You could try experimenting with the underlying Socket, using the properties `cl.Client.Blocking` and `cl.Client.ReceiveTimeout`. My problem is that I don't get any delay using your code so it's hard to check where that delay might be defined.  
On another note, would it be possible to check if a complete message has been received instead of checking the returned length? That would probably be a better solution in the long run, since network delays could cause your code to finish reading to early even with a 20 seconds delay.

Comment: I actually have a solution to my specific problem. It turns out I can tell when the message ends (pretty much your suggestion). However, the question is more general, and I'd still be interested in the answer.

Comment: @Shahar Yes, I agree. Could you try running your code towards another server, you might connect to `www.google.com:80` and send `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"`.

Comment: All of the data is returned in the first call (the second call returns 0)